# Show and alter oracle table in JSP page using Java

Tags: java, oracle, jsp

I want to show oracle table list in dropdown menu in JSP, after select a particular table I want to add or delete field on that table.I am trying this in java but couldn't bind it with JSP.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TableCreation {                                                     

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

 System.out.println("Please provide below details to connect Oracle Database");
 System.out.println("Enter Database");
 String dbName = scanner.next();
 System.out.println("Enter UserName");
 String userName = scanner.next();
 System.out.println("Enter Password");
 String password = scanner.next();
 System.out.println("Enter Table Name");
 String tablename = scanner.next();
 System.out.println("Enter Field Name");
 String columnname = scanner.next();
 System.out.println("ADD Field Name");
 String addcolumn = scanner.next();

 Statement statement;
 Connection connection = null;

 try {

 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

 } 
 catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
 }

 try {

 connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
 "jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.17.23.25:1521:" + dbName, userName,
 password);

 } 
 catch (SQLException e) {
 }
 if (connection != null) {
 System.out.println("Successfullly connected to Oracle DB");

 try {
     statement = connection.createStatement();
     String tableCreateQuery = "create table " +tablename+"("+
             columnname
             +" varchar2(10))";
 statement.executeUpdate(tableCreateQuery);
 System.out.println("Table Created Successfully");
 String query1 = "ALTER TABLE"+tablename+ "ADD" +
         addcolumn
         + "varchar2(10) ";
 statement.executeUpdate(query1);
 } 
 catch (SQLException e) {
    }
 } 
 else {
 System.out.println("Failed to connect to Oracle DB");
     }
  }
}
```

For listing table I use this query

```
statement = connection.createStatement();
     String tableListQuery = "select table_name from user_tables order by table_name";

     ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(tableListQuery);
 while (rs.next()) {

                String tablename = rs.getString("table_name");
                System.out.println(tablename);
            }
```

Comment: You can try using select table_name from all_tables instead.

Comment: How could I show all table from oracle name in JSP combobox using above query.

Answer (score 0):

@In response to your last comment. On the server side (in a servlet or JSP), populate a list containing all the tables

```
 List<String> tables = new ArrayList<String>();
  while (rs.next()) {

            String tablename = rs.getString("table_name");
            tables.add(tablename);
        }

//add this list to a request object (either create a servlet or use your jsp)

request.setAttribute("tables", tables);
```

In your JSP, create a scriptlet

```
import="java.util.List"%>//this import is needed
<%
List<String> tables = (List<String>)request.getAttribute("tables");
//create dropdown
out.print("<select id=\"ddTables\">");
for(int i=0; i<tables.size();i++){
 out.print("<option>tables.get(i)</option>);
}
out.print("</select>");
 %>
```

Note that you can't do this in a console application like you're trying. You either have to create a servlet or place everything in your JSP (which is an extremely bad design).

In fact, even using scriptlets is not recommended. Use JSTL instead.